# I want if I type @ in textarea of CK-Editor then a dropdown of members should be shown then on select, it will be paste into the editor textarea

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core, ckeditor

Here is my code to implement editor and to fetch the data from database.

```
<script src="~/js/ckeditor5-build-classic-master/build/ckeditor.js"></script>

<div class="card-body" contenteditable="true" id="areaId" data-href="@item.Id" onclick="createEditor(@areaId)">
                        @Html.Raw(item.Description)
                    </div>

<script>
var editors = new Map();
 function createEditor(elementToReplace) {

            return ClassicEditor
                .create(elementToReplace)
                .then(editor => {
                    editors.set(elementToReplace, editor);

                })
                .catch(err => console.error(err.stack));
        }

 $("#hoverIds").bind('keyup', function (event) {
           // debugger;
            var Val = $(this).find("p:first").text();
            var mName = "";
           if (Val.includes("@@")){
              // debugger;
              var mentionChar="@@";
                var charIndex = Val.indexOf("@@")+1;
                var setIndex=charIndex;
                while (Val[charIndex] !=null) {
                    mName+=Val[charIndex];
                    mentionChar += Val[charIndex];
                    charIndex++;
                }
             if(mName.length>=2){
               $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("getMentionList", "Note")',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: { Alphabet: mName },
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        debugger;
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                            {
                                var Mame = data[i].name;
                            }
                            //Val.replace(mentionChar, Mame);
                            $(this)find("p:first").text().replace(mentionChar, Mame);

                    }
               });
             }
           }
});
</script>
```

I also tried the autocomplete method of jquery but it doesn't work for editor. I am getting the data from database correctly but I'm not able to paste it in editor textarea to show it in dropdown form like in Microsoft Teams if I type @, then it will show the all names of members in a group. You can see the image for error understanding. If I type @da then it will return me Daryl Crouse. [image]